# Perl regex - remove all characters except alphanumeric characters and comma

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code:

```
my $str = 'Uploaded 07-02▒05:14, Size 212.14▒MiB, ULed by someone';
print "Pre:".$str."\n";
my $str =~ s/^[a-zA-z0-9,]//g;
print "Post:".$str."\n";
```

My aim was to remove those special characters and spaces so that I could split the string for further processing.

With the regex above, I was trying to remove all characters except alphanumeric characters and comma. Unfortunately I am getting a blank line. I'm a beginner to regex and would like to know what is wrong with my expression.

Comment: use strict; use warnings; You already declared $str at string one, and you again declaring it on string three

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have three errors conspiring to break your program. If you had `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your code as you should have then Perl would have printed messages to alert you

- You have declared a second `$str`, which is therefore `undef` and is printed as an empty string
- You have the caret outside the character class, so it is acting as a start-of-string anchor instead of negating the class
- You have `[a-zA-z0-9]` as your character class. `A-z` includes the characters `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, and `` ` `` as well as the upper and lower case alphabet. You need `[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead

Here is some working code. Your text string contains a Unicode character *U+2592 Medium Shade* so I've had to `use utf8` to mark the code as being encoded in UTF-8, and `use open` to set STDOUT to accept UTF-8 encoding

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf-8) /;

my $str = 'Uploaded 07-02▒05:14, Size 212.14▒MiB, ULed by someone';

print "Pre: $str\n";

$str =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9,]//g;

print "Post: $str\n";
```

#### output

```
Pre: Uploaded 07-02▒05:14, Size 212.14▒MiB, ULed by someone
Post: Uploaded07020514,Size21214MiB,ULedbysomeone
```

Comment: sometimes is usefull not to remove, but replace problematic character. then you should replace $str =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9,]//g;    by   $str =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9,]/X/g;  where X is your replacement.

Answer (score 6):

> I was trying to remove all characters except alphanumeric characters and comma.

You need to use:

```
$str =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9,]+//g;
```

Notice `^` as first character inside `[...]` that negates every character inside character class denoted by `[...]`

`[^a-zA-Z0-9,]+` will match 1 or more of anything that is not letter, digit or comma.

Comment: What is the intention when the caret is inserted outside the square brackets?

Comment: `^` is called start anchor outside `[...]` and is used to match line start .

Comment: Unfortunately even with this edit, the string is printed as null.

Comment: [See this working demo](http://ideone.com/cTJrSb) You need to remove `my` 2nd time as I showed in my answer also. Using `my` will initialize the variable again.

Comment: Perils of forgetting to `use warnings`. Thank you

Comment: Of course it is incorrect, bad copy/paste from question. Thanks for pointing it out, corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative:

```
$str =~ s/[^\p{PosixAlnum},]//g;
```

e.g. remove anything what isn't posix alphanumeric or comma.

Comment: @Alexander: This `\p{...}` is a *Unicode property*. There is a list of those available in [`perldoc perluniprops`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove special characters from string

```
$str =~ s/[^[:print:]]//g;
```

OR

```
$str =~ s/[^[print:]]//g;
```

Comment: This replace all non printable characters like ^M into null

Answer (score -1):

`sed "s/[^a-zA-Z ]//g"` you can do this in bash. pointless but interesting

Comment: The question asks about Perl, not Bash. Also, since this is about a full script and not a one-liner, your answer doesn't actually answer the question, which was to remove some characters from the **variable** `$str`. Moreover, this answer is wrong because it doesn't take digits and commas into account.